# Remove or replace LF from CSV file

Tags: csv, notepad++, eol

I have some huge CSV files where sometimes the lines end with `LF` instead of `CRLF`, for example:

```
pippo LF
pluto CRLF
```

I want to convert these two lines into a single line, like `pippo pluto CRLF`.

I'm trying to do this in Notepad++ (Windows 7), but I'm not able to do it...

Comment: So you don't want to replace all occurrences of `LF` with `CRLF`? – Instead, do you want to _remove_ all occurrences of `LF`? (If I misunderstood you, my edit is wrong.)

Answer (score 10):

To do so:

```
Ctrl + F
Go to the "Replace" tab
In "Find What" paste: ([^\r])\n
In "Replace with" paste: \1
Choose "Regular expression" in "Search Mode"
Click "Replace All"
```

Answer (score 4):

In "Edit" menu, choose "Convert line feed" and "Convert to windows format (CRLF).

NB: I'm not quite sure of the labels because I have not an english version of Notepad++.

Notepad++ menus evolve from version to version. In the English version of Notepad++ 6.3.2 from the **Edit** menu, select **EOL Conversions** => **Windows Format**.

Answer (score 1):

Just replace all the `\r` with `""`.

To do so:

1. `Ctrl+F`
2. Go to "Reaplace" tab
3. In "Find What" paste: `\r`
4. In "Replace with" paste: ""
5. Choose "Extended" in "Search Mode"
6. Replace All

Comment: Hi, I solved using a trick: Replace \n with null, and after that replace \r with \r\n. Thanks